# cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined - Angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

Component.ts

```
// Component containing function
Public myData(){
    this.myService.getData()
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            catchError((err: any) => {
                this.myRows = [];
                return throwError(err);
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                console.log('In Finally');
            })
        )
        .subscribe((rows) => {
            this.myRows = rows;
            // Do something
        });
}
```

myService.ts

```
// Service Call
public getData(): Observable < customer[] > {
    const url = 'some url';
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
        map(this.checkForError),
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            return throwError(err);
        }),
        map(this.myJson),
        share()
    );
}
```

spec.ts

```
    // Test Case
    it('should test', () => {
        let test =  spyOn(myService, 'getData');
        component.myData();
        expect(test).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Couldn't resolve this error. Not able to find an easy way of writing test case for service call. How can we resolve the pipe error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems to be on `this.myService.getData().pipe(...`
Because in your test, you spy on "getData" but you are not returning any value and particularly not an Observable from the spy.

What you may want to do in your test :

```
const customers = []; // define here your testing array
spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(customers)); // "of" is a Rxjs function to create an Observable
```

Comment: With this approach, the test case will pass but the code coverage will not happen.  Is there any other way round?

Comment: If you are writing unit tests, you should not really call your service in the component test. Instead, you should writes unit tests for the component and unit tests for the service. This approach result in tests easier to write, to read and thus to maintain.

Comment: On the other hand, if you really want to call your service method, you must properly mock ``this.http.get(url)`` because you don't want to make a real http call. see for example this article to mock http calls https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with an async function like this :

```js
it('should test', fakeAsync(() => { // Add FakeAsync
    let test =  spyOn(myService, 'getData');
    component.myData();
    tick(); // Add this
    expect(test).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

Comment: Tried the solution provided above but still getting the same error.

Answer (score -7):

try this:

declare pipe is in ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({                   //use for filter pipe
  name: "dataFilter"
})
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question.  rxjs pipe and angular pipe are completely different